# Xcode analyzer "efficiency"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I spent 1 hour on solving a bug: i was releasing an object that I didn't have ownership (ie I didn't send it copy, alloc, new).
The analyzer (Cmd-Shif-A) didn't detect that error while it can detect an object that hasn't been released.

I think it's not normal, is it a bug or a "missing functionality"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static analysis is not magic; there are many limitations and the analyser that Xcode uses is a work in progress.  It is there only as an aid, it can't totally debug your application for you.

If you think you have come across a case where you think the analyser could have found the problem, then [report a bug](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/filing_bugs.html).

Comment: What Jim said; please, please, please report a bug and, if at all possible, provide a source example.  The analyzer team is very responsive to such things!!